# protoc-jar-maven-plugin unable to find dependent proto files in the same directory

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, protobuf-java

I have a directory that stores all of my proto files at `${basedir}/resources/proto/`, there is a file `a.proto` in which imports another proto file via `resources/proto/b.proto`. I tried the following configuration but it does not work as intended:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.os72</groupId>
  <artifactId>protoc-jar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-sources</phase>
      <configuration>
        <inputDirectories>
          <include>${basedir}/resources/proto</include>
        </inputDirectories>
        <includeDirectories>
          <include>${basedir}/resources/proto</include>
        </includeDirectories>
        <outputTargets>
          <outputTarget>
            <type>java</type>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
          </outputTarget>
        </outputTargets>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm pretty sure the includeDirectories tag is just extra and does nothing, and my error is `[ERROR] /home/${basedir}/resources/proto/a.proto [0:0]: resources/proto/b.proto: File not found.`

How can I properly include the protobuf directories so it can compile? I cannot change the proto files as it is a git submodule therefore I need to work around the current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, include directory needs to directly include the basedir as the protobuf files tries to discover them through the full path.